# Can Python do Factory Method design pattern?

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, factory-pattern, mcu

I did it in **C** using an array of *function pointers*.  The pointers are randomly accessed and used to call their pointed-to function, which runs a unique animated light pattern in a **WS2812B LED strip** [using the **ADAFruit NeoPixel library**].  But, I want to **OOP** it up [for 1, 'cuz OOP makes it easier to design new animations]!

I tried in **C++**, but it's been a few decades, so I'm rusty.  Which places me at a nexus - do I re-bone up on **C++**, or use this as incentive to finally learn **Python**?

That's the why.  Here's the what:

Since this runs in a memory meager **MCU** environment, I want the animation routines to only take as much memory as they need, and then when done, *release* that memory.  So, I want to avoid something like: Instantiating a bunch of animation objects, and loading those into an array, to be indexed at random.  That would cram Heap/Stack with the sum of memory needed by ALL the animation objects at once -- which would put a greater constraint on the number of animations that could exist in the MCU [especially since RAM is usually in shorter supply than ROM/PROM].

No, I want to fill that array with something more like pointers to "instantiation" functions, that, when called, instantiate the ONE, *selected* animation object.  And, then, when that animation is finished, does a "delete"/stimulates destructors/etc. so memory is exactly cleared [i.e. no *memory leaks*].

My **C++** implementation is riddled with memory leaks [no *memory management* in C++] -- though, far less than when I started, so I'm getting better [a little **Monty** nod, there].

So... do I continue my pursuit of the restoration of my **C++** magnificence [I was once a "go-to expert"], or do I dump **C++** and take up **Python**?  The only tipping point is: *CAN PYTHON DO THE JOB*?

OK, another tipping point might be my fondness for **Operator Overloading** ;)

**BTW:** The MCU I'm currently using is the **SeeedStudio XIAO**, which is a fast and ferrous little bugger, so, even if Python is a bit more *dilatory* than C++ [because of the extra overhead], no worries [much?].

Comment: Yes, you can implement the factory pattern in Python, the same way you would in C, C++, Java, or any other object oriented programming language.

Comment: You can also overload operators in Python.

Comment: In otherwords, there's a way to programmatically create and destroy objects such that the memory they were using is "managed" [e.g. garbage collected], so one can avoid cramming memory with ALL the objects at once, even though only one is being used at a time?  I just want to make sure we're on the same page.  And, if so, is this so for MCU implementations [which are notoriously NOT memory managed]?

Comment: This is the page I'm reading from. [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Python as a language doesn't discuss memory. The implementations of python I know of are all managed. If your C++ has memory leaks, you need to learn what RAII is